# Workflow for adding and editing tables in MS Access with Azure SQL Database Backend

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, azure, azure-sql-database, ms-access-2013

There are a lot of articles and blogs detailing the steps to link/split/migrate an MS Access app so that the back end is hosted on Azure SQL, e.g. [this one](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/cloud/link-to-azure-sql-database.html).

However, all those articles seem to assume that table structure is in a fixed and final state.

But what if I'm just starting out with the development? If I link the back end to Azure SQL at the onset, do I then proceed to create tables in Access or directly on the Azure DB? What's the proper development workflow for keeping the synchronization while adding and editing tables?

Comment: This is only a personal opinion.
Normally we develop on local servers or worstations.
In order to update customer database, we have db scripts that run agains all final production db. Note that we keep documentation on every db structure change and keep the scripts always updated.

Comment: Ah yes that would be the right approach when developing professionally. But let's say I'm allowed to develop directly on production - how do I create and edit tables when the back end is a SQL server? Do I create them in Access or directly on SQL server?

Comment: I would suggest that you can define your tables, relations, stored procedures direct on Azure... If you write code and db definitions in a single step process it goes quicker, so you can also test your code against the final db and have no performance surprises...

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post details how to connect Access to SQLDB:
https://blogs.office.com/2012/08/08/access-2013-and-sql-server/
Let me know if this helps